# Javascript toFixed is not appearing

Tags: javascript, decimal

i'm new to javascript and this is very sinmple question but why i can not get the results as decimals in these codes?

```
var num1 = document.getElementById('ara_toplam').value;
var num2 = document.getElementById('indirim').value;
var num3 = parseFloat(num1) * parseFloat(num2) / 100;
var result1 = parseFloat(num1) - parseFloat(num3);
if (!isNaN(result1)) {
    document.getElementById('genel_toplam').value = result1.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('genel_toplam1').innerHTML = result1.toFixed(2);
    $('label[for="indirim1"]').text(num3).toFixed(2);
}
```

result1.toFixed(2) this is what i need but toFixed is not appearing while writing the codes. Even if i write, it doesn't show result1 in decimals.

Comment: What exactly is not working? What happens for `console.log(result1.toFixed(2))`? Where do you want to run `toFixed`?

Comment: I'm confused, you don't have any `toFixed` in the code you supplied.

Comment: I have added toFixed(2) to the 3 lines after if(!isNaN(result1)) where i need to use.

Comment: After the edit we can see, that you're not assigning the fixed value to the label, it should be `$('label[for="indirim1"]').text(num3.toFixed(2));` It would be also interesting to know, when you're running this code, and the relevant HTML would also be nice ...

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't know what elements you are using, but see this JSFiddle for examples how to use toFixed:

http://jsfiddle.net/Q8KVC/3680/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var num1 = document.getElementById('ara_toplam').value;
   var num2 = document.getElementById('indirim').value;
   var num3 = parseFloat(num1) * parseFloat(num2) / 100;
   var result1 = parseFloat(num1) - parseFloat(num3);
   if (!isNaN(result1)) {
      document.getElementById('genel_toplam').value = result1.toFixed(2);
      document.getElementById('genel_toplam1').innerHTML = result1.toFixed(2);
      document.getElementById('toFixed').value= num3.toFixed(3);
      //document.querySelector('[for="toFixed"]').innerText = num3.toFixed(3);
     $('label[for="toFixed"]').text(num3.toFixed(2));
    }
});
```

Make sure you are using the right properties for assigning values to any DOM element.

Answer (score -2):

Here is an example of `3.00` being displayed on the console:

```js
var result1 = 3;
console.log(result1.toFixed(2))
```

I've also made a plunker to show the functionality of the `.toFixed()` method:
https://plnkr.co/edit/E1DSAZLP76OiSy4c6uu3?p=preview

I see the problem in:
`$('label[for="indirim1"]').text(num3).toFixed(2);`
The return type of `.text(num3)` function is not a number, but a jQuery object. You should apply the `toFixed()` method to a number therefore:

`$('label[for="indirim1"]').text(num3.toFixed(2));`

Comment: _"Make sure you have a number with decimal points"_: What? Try using `3` instead of `3.1415`.

Comment: You just disproved yourself: *"Make sure you have a number with decimal points"*...